# What are the new Features of Spring 3 (compared to Spring 2.5)?

Tags: java, spring

Does someone can tell me what's new in Spring 3 and the difference to two (Spring 2.5 and Spring 3)?

Answer (score 6):

See [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.html) whats new in Spring 3.0.

Answer (score 6):

Here are some excerpts from the page [New Features and Enhancements in Spring 3.0](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.html) with links to the relevant technologies:

### Java 5

> The entire framework code has been revised to take advantage of Java 5
>   features like [generics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java), [varargs](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html) and other language
>   improvements. We have done our best to still keep the code backwards
>   compatible. We now have consistent use of generic [Collections](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) and
>   [Maps](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), consistent use of generic [FactoryBeans](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-extension-factorybean), and also
>   consistent resolution of bridge methods in the [Spring AOP API](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html).
>   Generic [ApplicationListeners](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-functionality-events) automatically receive specific event
>   types only. All callback interfaces such as [TransactionCallback](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.1.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionCallback.html)
>   and [HibernateCallback](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateCallback.html) declare a generic result value now.
>   Overall, the Spring core codebase is now freshly revised and optimized
>   for Java 5.
>
> Spring's [TaskExecutor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/task/TaskExecutor.html) abstraction has been updated for close
>   integration with Java 5's [java.util.concurrent](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) facilities. We
>   provide first-class support for [Callables](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) and [Futures](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) now,
>   as well as [ExecutorService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) adapters, [ThreadFactory](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadFactory.html)
>   integration, etc. This has been aligned with [JSR-236](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=236)
>   (Concurrency Utilities for Java EE 6) as far as possible. Furthermore,
>   we provide support for asynchronous method invocations through the use
>   of the new [@Async](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Async.html) annotation (or EJB 3.1's [@Asynchronous](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Asynchronous.html)
>   annotation).

### Overview of new features

> This is a list of new features for Spring 3.0. We will cover these
>   features in more detail later in this section.
>
> - [Spring Expression Language](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html)
> - [IoC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html) enhancements/[Java based bean metadata](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java)
> - General-purpose [type conversion system](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#core-convert) and [field formatting
>     system](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#format)
> - [Object to XML mapping functionality](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/oxm.html) (OXM) moved from [Spring
>     Web Services](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/) project
> - [Comprehensive REST support](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.html#d0e1188)
> - [@MVC additions](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.html#d0e1221)
> - [Declarative model validation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.html#new-feature-validation)
> - [Early support for Java EE 6](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.html#new-feature-jee-6)
> - [Embedded database support](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.html#new-feature-embedded-databases)

Answer (score 0):

Check this http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Whats-New-in-Spring-3.0